# Using sed to only print parts of a line containing a word

Tags: sed

I am trying to create one line, containing the Temperature values of my NVMe drives, using ONLY sed.

The Output of nvme using the smart log on the first chip

```
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1

Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1
namespace-id:ffffffff 
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 40 C 
available_spare                     : 100% 
available_spare_threshold           : 10% 
percentage_used                     : 0% 
data_units_read                     : 88.659 
data_units_written                  : 351.868 
host_read_commands                  : 659.265
host_write_commands                 : 787.770 
controller_busy_time                : 5 
power_cycles                        : 17 
power_on_hours                      : 6 
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 1 
media_errors                        : 0 
num_err_log_entries                 : 2 
Warning Temperature Time            : 0 
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0 
Temperature Sensor 1                : 40 C 
Temperature Sensor 2                : 43 C 
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0 
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0 
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0 
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
```

the first step would be to just select the Lines ending with a "C" with

```
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1 | sed -n '/C$/p'
temperature                         : 40 C
Temperature Sensor 1                : 40 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 43 C
```

but instead of printing them I want to remove all text before the colon, and remove the newlines and get the Output to:

```
 40 C 40 C 43 C
```

but I am getting stuck with the whole pattern/holding space. Any help would be appreciated.

***This can only be achieved with awk, so ignore the arithmetic request***

*Bonus goal*

Add the device name, degree symbol, and show only the difference of the Sensors:

```
nvme0n1 40°C +0°C +3°C
```

Comment: I usggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: I use awk often, but I am trying to get my mind around sed now...

Comment: sed is *not* good at arithmetic.

Comment: `show only the difference` It's close to impossible to substract numbers in `sed`. In your input there's a space after `C`.

Comment: Have a look at [how complicated](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#wc-_002dc) even simple counting operations are in sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*: *//; /C *$/H; ${g;s/\n//g;p}'
```

Output:

```
40 C 40 C 43 C
```

---

```
sed -n 's/.*: *//; s/ $//; 1h; /C *$/H; ${g;s/\n/ /g;p}' file
```

Output:

```
nvme0n1 40 C 40 C 43 C
```

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '
    # if it's a line ending with C, then ignore it
    /C $/!d;
    # ignore stuff before :
    s/.*: //;
    # replace <space>C with °C
    s/ C/°C/;
    # Remove all spaces. There is a space after C
    s/ //g;
    # append a <newline>+line into hold space
    H
    # On the last line
    ${
       # Take stuff from the hold space
       x;   # or `g`
       # Remove leading newline
       s/^\n//;
       # join lines with spaces
       s/\n/ /g;
       # print and exit
       p; q;
    };
'
```

would output:

```
40°C 40°C 43°C
```

`sed` is a simple regex-replace utility. To for example substract two numbers in sed, you would basically have to generate all possible combinations: `sed 's/1-1/0/; s/2-1/1/; s/3-1/2/; s/ ... all possible combinations of numbers ... '`.

To calculate the difference between numbers, use `awk`.

Comment: ok.. then disregard the Bonus awk arithmetic. 

thanks for the explanation @KamilCuk

Comment: The solution @Cyrus provided is what I am using so far, as I am still fighting to get the HOLD concept in my head. Adding --debug really helps. But I want to get your version right. The approach is different, more complex, but also more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using GNU `sed` would be

```
sed -E 's/^/\n/; :a; s/\n.*: ([0-9]+ C )$/\1/; s/\n.*//; $!{N; ba}'
```

This version doesn't use the hold buffer, but probably is less efficient than those that use it.